# change Blackberry Clock on usbConnectionStateChange

Tags: java, blackberry, listener, clock

I'm trying to create an app that replaces the default clock when a usbconnection is made. I can't get my code to work. I added the listener like this UiApplication.getUiApplication().addSystemListener(this); in my MainScreen and overrode

```
public void usbConnectionStateChange(int state)
        {
            switch (state)
            {
                // USB cable is connected
                case USB_STATE_CABLE_CONNECTED:
                    pushScreen(new MyScreen());
                    break;
                // USB cable is disconnected
                case USB_STATE_CABLE_DISCONNECTED:
                    //message("Cable disconnected");
                    //if (_connected)
                    //{
                      //  abort();
                    //}
                    break;                
            }
        }
```

I'm trying to push MyScreen() when a USB connection is made but it's not working.
EDIT: I enabled my app to run on startup too

Comment: What is it that you expect to happen?   Have you added debug statements to see if this code is executing at all?

Comment: I added a breakpoint at the method and created local variable int i = 0;, the program stops at the breakpoint and the i variable is in scope so the code is executing. I'm trying to make MyScreen() be pushed onto the display when the usbconnection is detected.

Comment: SOLVED: changed the pushScreen() to requestForeground()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changed PushScreen() to requestForeground()